# How to keep old value in MySQL on update of column?

Tags: python, mysql

I am updating a MySQL 5.7.32 table in python 3.x where sometimes the value for status is set and aometimes it is not.

In order to not throw an error in case the item is not present, I set it to None:

```
    if not 'status'             in item: item['status'] = None
```

Now it looks like this will set the value of the dataset tu NULL, therefore erase any old values I might have had:

```
    ...
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                    `STATUS` = %s
                """, (
                    item['status'],
```

How can I keep the (long complex query) but set the value to something else so it does not update?

Minimal example:

```
    if not 'status'             in item: item['status'] = `STATUS`

    self.curr.execute(""" 
        INSERT INTO product_catalog (
            `ARTICLE_ID`, 
            `STATUS`
        ) 
        VALUES (%s, %s)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
            `STATUS` = %s
        """, (
            item['ARTICLE_ID'],                       
            item['status'],                       
            item['status']                       
        )
    )
```

Comment: Hi merlin, could you provide some kind of `sandbox` for your problem, like a snippet of code and a schema for your base ?

Comment: Hi @smeden I added a minimal code example to further illustrate it. In some cases there is no status. So in line 1 I want to make sure the status stays like it is in case an update occures. Currently I have = None. Which will set it to NULL unfortunatelly. = 'STATUS' does not work, seems like a python syntax problem I have. In the case of no status I would like to set STATUS = STATUS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an expression in your update part to check if the value is `null`, e.g. use [`COALESCE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `STATUS` = COALESCE(%s, `STATUS`)
""", (..., item['status'])
```

`COALESCE()` returns the first parameter (so the value of `%s`) if it isn't `null`, otherwise the second parameter, in this case the current column value, which is the behaviour you are looking for.

You can simplify your statement further by using the [`VALUE(columnname)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax for `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, which refers to the new value you tried to insert, so you do not need to repeat the parameter:

```
  INSERT INTO product_catalog (`ARTICLE_ID`, `STATUS`)
  VALUES (%s, %s)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    `STATUS` = COALESCE(VALUE(`STATUS`), `STATUS`)
""", (item['ARTICLE_ID'], item['status'])
```

Since MySQL 8.0.20, this syntax is deprecated though (but still works for now), and is replaced by using aliases:

```
  INSERT INTO product_catalog (`ARTICLE_ID`, `STATUS`)
  VALUES (%s, %s) AS new
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    `STATUS` = COALESCE(new.`STATUS`, product_catalog.`STATUS`)
""", (item['ARTICLE_ID'], item['status'])
```

This defines an alias (here `new`) for the inserted row, which you can reuse in your `update` part, similar to `value()`.